# Dplyr select ends_with

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm starting with a df that looks like this:

```
  sample_id        target_id length     eff_length est_counts    tpm   class
1 SRR3884838C      (A)n     69          70          0        0.00000     0
2 SRR3884838C     (AC)n     69          70          0        0.00000     0
3 SRR3884838C     (AG)n     69          70          0        0.00000     0
4 SRR3884838C     (AT)n     69          70          5        15.98870    0
```

I would like to use dplyr's select function to select only sample_ids that end with the letter C, as well as the target_id and tpm.

Example data:

```
> dput(droplevels(head(te,4)))
structure(list(sample_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "SRR3884838C", class = "factor"), 
target_id = structure(1:4, .Label = c("(A)n", "(AC)n", "(AG)n", 
"(AT)n"), class = "factor"), length = c(69L, 69L, 69L, 69L
), eff_length = c(70L, 70L, 70L, 70L), est_counts = c(0, 
0, 0, 5), tpm = c(0, 0, 0, 15.9887), class = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L)), .Names = c("sample_id", "target_id", "length", "eff_length", 
"est_counts", "tpm", "class"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried using the following:

```
  teC <- select(te, (sample_id, ends_with("C")), target_id, tpm)
```

Which gives me the sample_id, target_id and tpm but does not select only the sample_id's that end with C eg:

```
      sample_id        target_id  tpm
9759  SRR3884843CxS   Tigger15a   0.00000e+00
9760  SRR3884843CxS   Tigger16a   0.00000e+00
9761  SRR3884843CxS   Tigger16b   0.00000e+00
```

Am I doing something wrong with select? I was able to work on example data from a tutorial site without issue.

Comment: When would `sample_id` ever end with `"C"`? Could you provide an example?

Comment: The first block of code has an example that ends with C instead of my other endings (eg. CxS), does that make sense? Please let me know if I need to clarify more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select` is used to keep variables (read: columns) by name, which is what you're doing with `sample_id`, `target_id`, and `tmp`. If you want to further filter by the values within `sample_id`, then add `filter`:

```
teC <- te %>% select(sample_id, target_id, tpm) %>% filter(grepl("C$", sample_id))
```

The regular expression `"C$"` will match strings that end with "C"; `"CxS$"` will match strings ending with "CxS"; and `"(C|CxS)$"` will match both.

Comment: So I can't use select to grab specific names within in a column like here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-complete-catalog-of-argument-variations-of-select-in-dplyr/

I copy and pasted your answer and got the error 

`Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: 'nchar()' requires a character vector.`

I am unfamiliar with the use of %>% so I will need to figure that out.

Comment: Actually this is incorrect at the moment -- `endswith` is a "helper" function for `select` (for grabbing columns with certain names) -- I will update this answer to correctly match strings in `sample_id`

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, but the corrected version should work. No, you can't use `endsWith` (from dplyr) to match values in a column -- it's only meant to be used to match column names themselves (useful for large data.frames). The `%>%` operator is known as the "pipe" operator -- it allows you to call functions on data.frames with the syntax `my_dframe %>% select(...) %>% filter(...)`, so that you don't have to repeatedly pass your data.frame as you "chain" functions.

Comment: Thank you, that appears to work. If I have a sample_id that ends with SxC instead of just C, is there a way to filter it so that I only end up with SxC or C? Will grepl("C$", sample_id)) always grab sample_id that ends with CxS?

Comment: I updated my answer again -- let me know if that doesn't make sense. If it turns out you need to match more complex/numerous patterns in your `sample_id` column, then I suggest you either read up on regular expressions in R, or ask a new SO question. (This is perhaps a good starting point on regular expressions: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/74603_76cd14d5983f47408fdf0b323550b846.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to figure out how to filter out the ones that end with just 'C' and keep the ones that end with 'SxC' and vice versa